# Addition of contextmenu for gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to bind each and every row in my gridview with context menu. That menu should contain options like Edit , Delete . can anybody please give me a sample code for that and also I want to know where can I get this contextmenu.dll file. Please help me out, I have tried every kown way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend the control see [this](http://aspalliance.com/946_Extended_GridView_Control.all)

Or you can use JQuery for the context menu.
See [Context Menu on right click ASP.NET gridview](http://technico.qnownow.com/context-menu-on-right-click-in-asp-net-gridview-control/) or http://rsolberg.com/contextmenuaspnet/

Comment: Thank you for your help.                                          1.but does this Extended GridView Control work properly with updatepanel?                                                          2.where can I find this contextmenu.dll do you have any idea?

Comment: A little late I know but just FYI: "contextmenu" is a jquery javascript library (so look on NuGet for jquery.contextMenu.js)